# Get values for ENUMs in Postgres?

Tags: postgresql

I created an enum like this:

```
CREATE TYPE status as ENUM ('INVALID', 'VALID', 'EXPIRED');
```

How can I query the database to get the possible values for this enum? I tried something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM status;
```

Doesn't work. Any ideas as to how to do this?

Answer (score 2):

Something like this:

```
select e.enumlabel
from pg_type t 
   join pg_enum e on t.oid = e.enumtypid  
   join pg_catalog.pg_namespace n ON n.oid = t.typnamespace
where t.typname = 'status'
  and n.nspname = 'public';
```

Answer (score 0):

If `psql`, then `\dT+`:

```
\dT+ status
```